# horde cannot save contacts with not latin characters

Tags: email, horde

I noticed that when I try to add a sender to address Book with non latin characters (greek) in its name, the horde cannot save it and the following message appears:"server error when perfoming search".
Any solutions or from where to start to search?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.horde.org/community/support

Answer (score 0):

> In particular, there might be problems with some non-latin characters
>   with addressbook entries, so be sure you check those and correct them,
>   we are sorry that there was no good way to automatically handle this
>   problem

Quoted from [here](https://help.riseup.net/en/email/webmail/where-is-imp)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but the whole name is in greek...So there isnt any solution available?